# tsql columns to rows withut pivot /unpivot function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to go from columns to rows. Not sure how to go about best way
Pivot and Unpivot commands not available on our 2008R2 server.  I tried a Union All setup but couldn't seem to get that to work

```
Type     S100                  S50 (column header row)

Type1    5000.00               56760.00              
Type2    2345.00               87650.00
```

To

```
Denom   Type1        Type2   (column header row)
100     5000.00      2345.00 
50      56760.00     87650.00
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't have PIVOT / UNPIVOT available in 2008??? Those functions are absolutely there in 2008.

Comment: Our admin will not enable them to be used is what I meant.

Comment: I agree with Jason that they are generally more of a pain than they are worth. However, your admin cannot disable those functions, they are native to sql server. They may have a company rule that states you are not to use them though. ;)

Comment: I meant the compstinilty level is set to low so pivot will not run and hence disabled the feature. According to the error received

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't want to use PIVOT & UNPIVOT anyway... They are a bigger pain than they're worth. This should do the trick...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    TypeId CHAR(5),
    s100 MONEY,
    s50 MONEY 
    );
INSERT #TestData(TypeId, s100, s50) VALUES
    ('Type1', 5000.00, 56760.00),           
    ('Type2', 2345.00, 87650.00);

--SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

WITH 
    cte_Unpivot AS (
        SELECT 
            td.TypeId,
            d.Denom,
            d.cValue
        FROM 
            #TestData td
            CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (100, td.s100), (50, td.s50) ) d (Denom, cValue)
        )
SELECT 
    u.Denom,
    Type1 = SUM(CASE WHEN u.TypeId = 'Type1' THEN u.cValue END),
    Type2 = SUM(CASE WHEN u.TypeId = 'Type2' THEN u.cValue END)
FROM 
    cte_Unpivot u
GROUP BY
    u.Denom
ORDER BY 
    u.Denom DESC;
```

Results...

```
Denom       Type1                 Type2
----------- --------------------- ---------------------
100         5000.00               2345.00
50          56760.00              87650.00
```

Comment: A couple of very minor tweaks and it works perfectly. Thanks Jason you are a champp.

Comment: Glad to help. :)